# Where to put Database file in Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: database, eclipse, sqlite, rcp

I want to access SQLite DB file in my ECLIPSE RCP application. Where i have to put it in my application?
And also at exporting a product how to define the path of Database file.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the database file in your plugin and access it in the code by getting the plugin's Bundle. Look at the following article for examples on how to access a plugin's files: [Getting Access To Files In Eclipse RCP](http://lotuseclipsecorner.blogspot.com/2009/03/getting-access-to-files-in-eclipse-rcp.html)